# bind menu and submenu from database in asp net core entity framework mvc

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 tables in database Industry and Category. They are joined using IndustryId as primary key and Foreign key in tables.Now I want to show Industry as my main menu item and Related categories as my sub menu items of respective industries. I am using asp net mvc enity framework as my coding architecture with visual studio 2017.This is my first application on this architecture I want a brief explanation including models views and controllers step by step.I have done this binding earlier on asp net web forms without mvc. But entity frameworks is seems to be totally different from previous versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** based on user comment, he want to bind the data on load, making nested list, I will leave my old answer as it might help someone else, I will add the new answer as well, 
my suggestion is you pass List of Industries as a ViewBag, since there is foriegn key in categories which is industryid relating to industry table, ef will detect that relationship and represent it in your Industry Model as `virtual Collection<Category> Categories`, this represents all categories associated with this industry.
what you can do is pass it then using razor syntax do something like this in your view 
in your controller you pass it as viewbag

```
 ViewBag.Industries = dbContext.Industries.Include(x => x.Categories).ToList();
```

then in your view

```
    <!-- init your list -->
                <ul>
    <!-- loop through your viewbag -->
                foreach (var x in (List<Industry>) ViewBag.Industries)
                {
                  <li> x.IndustryName
    <!-- init your sub menu -->               
    <ul>
    <!-- loop through your categories of this industry x -->
    foreach(var c in x.Categories)
    { 
    <li> c.CategoryName </li>
    } 
                  </ul>
                  </li>
                }
<!-- loop end, close your list -->
</ul>
```

For People looking to update their menu content dynamically according to another menu value, read below:

What I do to solve such thing is, first create action which accepts industry id and return List or categories, I use ajax to call this action whenever my industry id list change in the front end (change event listener), then get the return as list of object, bind the data to my sub menu using jquery. 
something like

```
public ActionResult GetCategories(int IndustryID)
{
// this simple select query, retrieves all categories that have industry id provided 
var categories = dbContext.Categories.Where(c => c.IndustryId == IndustryID).ToList();
return Json(categories);
}
```

ajax code

```
 // industryId is the id of industry in your view, apply change event listener
$('#industryId').change(function () {
          // ajax call, get data
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "controllerhere")',
                data: { IndustryID: this.value},
                dataType: "json"
            }).done(function(data){
                  // Data recieved, get categories list, empty it, bind the new data 
                   var ddl = $("#categoriesList");
                ddl.empty();
                ddl.append($('<option>', {value: 0,text: 'Select'})); //Newly added
               // categoryID and CategoryName are properties in your category, these Names I assumed, they might change depending on your Model 
                $.each(data, function () {
                    ddl.append($('<option></option>').attr("value", this.CategoryID).text(this.CategoryName));
                });
            });
        });
```

I hope this answered your question, I am not sure what did you mean when you said entity framework is different, you can ask me more specific questions maybe i can help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want to bind those industries and categories on menu(Navigation Bars) on the top of my page not on any dropdown or click event.So can you give the solution for dynamically binding of navigation items on navigation bars.rest all question remains same

Comment: you can pass a list of industries, each one will have a list of categories, then you using Razor syntax, you can loop through the list of industries, and output the desired html.

Comment: It works.And hope will help others also on the same issue.

Comment: if it worked please mark as correct answer, I am glad I helped

Comment: your answer is correct and I marked it also. But What if I want to bind the navigation bars to a shared layout page. It will bind only in those pages where i have defined the function for binding in respective controllers. but that increases the no of lines of codes. I tried about partial view but didn't succeeded.So guide me to complete it correctly.

Comment: Hello, I would use render action, i would write my action in the baseController I am using, then use render action which will render the action that will render the menu, which will be in my baseController as I mentioned, read [this](http://devproconnections.com/development/how-use-aspnet-mvc-render-action-helpers)